# What is a GTK "render detail"?

Tags: c, icons, gtk, stock, gdkpixbuf

I was having temporary difficulties setting the icon of a window in my C program to a stock icon, and I almost asked how to do it, but then I created the GdkPixbuf I needed like this:

```
gtk_widget_render_icon(GTK_WIDGET(window),GTK_STOCK_CONVERT,-1,NULL)
```

The last argument is described by the documentation as "render detail to pass to theme engine. [allow-none]" ([here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-render-icon)). Since I have no idea what an appropriate value for that might be, I set it to NULL and hoped it would work. It did work, but now I want to know why.

What is this value supposed to be? Is there any possible repercussion if I leave it as NULL?

Comment: What version of Gtk are you using?

Comment: I'm using both GTK2 and GTK3, and I think this applies to both of them. The documentation was referring to GTK3, as the URL indicates.

Comment: I guess in that case I'd point out that the manual has a big warning indicating that this is a deprecated function.  Since the replacement function doesn't have this parameter, I think it's safe to assume that this parameter is specific to the Gtk2 theme engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation you linked to:

> `detail` should be a string that identifies the widget or code doing the rendering, so that theme engines can special-case rendering for that widget or code.

The way I interpret that is that you might set it to `"Wutaz-window-icon"` and then if theme writers needed to write a special case for your application, they could match that string.

However, the point is moot; as @MrEricSir points out, the function is deprecated.

Comment: Wow. I don't know how I missed that.